# Changing DataCell color changes other cells background

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a DataGrid that I populate in runtime with data from a SQLite database. When the user edits an cell in datagrid, I want that cell to change it's background color. So, this is a MCVE codebehind of what I did:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var r = dt.NewRow();
        r[0] = i ;
        r[1] = i * i;
        dt.Rows.Add(r);
    }
    myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}

private void myDataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditAction.ToString() == "Commit")
    {
        FrameworkElement element = e.Column.GetCellContent(e.Row);
        (element.Parent as DataGridCell).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" CellEditEnding="myDataGrid_CellEditEnding"/>
</Grid>
```

Problem is, whenever I scroll, I see other cells also painted in yellow. Also, depending on how I scroll, the yellow background jumps from my desired cell to another cell. This only happens if `EnableRowVirtualization` is set to `true`. Is there a way to do it without disabling it or this is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on Shou Risha link in his answer comment, I came up with a solution. The problem with disabling row virtualization is performance and memory, specially for large grids. To continue use virtualization and keep the background right, I had to cancel the `CleanUpVirtualizedItem` event if any of the row cells have a background color.

xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" CellEditEnding="myDataGrid_CellEditEnding" VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItem="myDataGrid_CleanUpVirtualizedItem"/>
</Grid>
```

codebehind:

```
private void myDataGrid_CleanUpVirtualizedItem(object sender, CleanUpVirtualizedItemEventArgs e)
{
    var row = e.UIElement as DataGridRow;
    for(int i = 0; i<(sender as DataGrid).Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        var cell = (DataGridCell)(sender as DataGrid).Columns[i].GetCellContent(row).Parent;
        if (cell.Background != Brushes.White) 
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found this solution on the net. I don't know if this is the right way to do it though. It's up to you I guess.

I  just added VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" to xaml:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" CellEditEnding="myDataGrid_CellEditEnding" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" />
```

I executed and saw that coloring doesn't jump to other cells now.

Comment: You can see it from the following link. Example has also a function named CleanUpVirtualizedItem. Maybe it will present you some extra option:   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7902d0a2-3df2-4070-a73a-12174456b6c3/wpf-datagrid-selected-row-background-color-change-using-c-without-xaml?forum=wpf

Comment: That stopped other cells from being color yellow, however, when you scroll, the yellow cell (the desired one) loses its color. The `CleanUpVirtualizedItem` that you mention is suposed to correct this, but the code provided is for row background, not cell background

Comment: Sorry I hadn't realized that when scrolling :/